# Wordpress pagination link rel start prev next

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta-tags, rel

I'm developing a lightweight feature-rich custom blogging system which generates exactly the same results as wordpress, but with only one table on one database and few php files. until now everything goes well and I'm about to finish it. the problem is that when I took a look at the source code of some well known blogs using wordpress I discovered the following:

1 - the main and its following pages (2,3,4...) only declare rel="index"

2 - the category and its following pages (2,3,4...) only declare rel="index"

3 - the article page and its following pages (2,3,4...) declare rel="index", rel="start", rel="prev" and rel="next" (depending of the article position)

so, only the main articles are linked together by link rel meta tags to form a series.

Now, why there isn't a meta linking between the listing pages (the index and its following pages)?

For my project, I already done this, the index and its following pages are meta linked together to form a series like mysite.com, mysite.com/page/2/ mysite.com/page/3/

and the pages within the same category are also in a series like mysite.com/cat-1/, mysite.com/cat-1/page/2/, mysite.com/cat-1/page/3/

and the articles of the whole blog are also in a series beginning from the first article to the last one.

SO WHY THIS IS NOT THE CASE FOR WORDPRESS? IS THIS A BAD PRACTICE? OR THEY JUST CAN'T DO IT WITH WORDPRESS??????

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with Wordpress, not sure why it's not a default header hook but some themes do implement it. If they don't, this plugin will set the right rel links for the paginated pages http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagination-rel-links/